# SQL BETWEEN missing data

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

```
 SELECT Field1
 FROM Table
 WHERE Field1 BETWEEN "A%" AND  "D%"
```

Example Data:

```
A432434324324
B435435435
C5654664546
D5465465546546
A768677687
B8768678768
A65446456546
B876867877868
```

Query outcome won't include "D" line, any ideas how to deal with it? ( I need to operate on text, not numbers).

Comment: @Harry: Did you read the question and missed the code?

Comment: @Harry: It is tagged both because MySQL is SQL too.

Comment: I did read it, simple copy paste error @juergend

Comment: Does `BETWEEN` run the `LIKE` operator on those strings? I wonder if those percentage symbols are literals? If that's the case, a regex clause might be good here.

Comment: you don't tag vb on c# code though do you? @juergend

Comment: @Harry: No, but I can tag C#-4 and C# on a question. Or why can't I tag SQL on a MySQL question. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm only asking to better my understanding. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave out the wildcard and try:

```
WHERE Field1 >= 'A' AND Field1 < 'E'
```

Or:

```
WHERE LEFT(Field1, 1) BETWEEN 'A' and 'D'
```

The `'%'` wildcard is used for `LIKE`, not for other string comparisons.

Two notes:

- The first version is better because it would allow MySQL to use an index on `Field1`.
- Use single quotes for string and date constants; this is the common syntax across all databases.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use wildcard in the "between" function. With you Query you get all values between A and the % sign and D and the % sign. Where the % sign is before the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

wildcards are used in searches. Here the RDBMS will take them as literals.
So, you get all lines, that start with a and have a second char with a value higher than the value of '%' and get all lines up to 'D' with a second char with a value lower than the value of '%'.

try
    between 'A' and 'DZZZ' 
or something like that.